# Array stored in numpy void returns no shape/length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, void

I have a large numpy void array loaded from a matlab struct. I can access the arrays stored inside the main array, but accessing their shape returns '()'. Accessing their length returns the error: len() of unsized object. Is there a way for me to access the shape of the sub-arrays?

```
arr = scipy.io.loadmat('mymatfile.mat', squeeze_me=True)
sub_arr = arr['a'][0]['b']['c']
print(sub_arr)
print(sub_arr.shape)
print(len(sub_arr))
```

returns: 
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
()

TypeError: len() of unsized object

Solution: sub_arr.item() returns a sized array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len` of an 0d array produces this error:

```
In [77]: x = np.array(123)
In [78]: x
Out[78]: array(123)
In [79]: x.shape
Out[79]: ()
In [80]: len(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-a7f4a5366567> in <module>()
----> 1 len(x)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

`loadmat` uses object dtype arrays to represent MATLAB cells and struct.

What's the `dtype` of `sub_arr`?  You may need to use sub_arr.item()`or`sub_arr[()]` to extract that item from the object layer.

Comment: The dtype is object.

Comment: So yes, you need `item()` or `[()]` to pull the contents out of the 0d object array.

Comment: That worked! I also figured out that setting the squeeze_me parameter to False also returns a normal array.

Comment: In MATLAB everything is 2d, so without `squeeze` you'll see a lot of (1,1) shape arrays, requiringing `[0,0]` indexing (`.item` still works if len is 1).

Comment: Do you know of a way to iterate through all the sub arrays within arr['a'] (without a for loop as that would be too slow)? Using your solutions only allows me to pull one sub array at a time.

Comment: Looks like `arr` is the dictionary, with `arr['a']` being the `a` variable on the MATLAB side.  It's hard to suggest anything more without a clearer picture of the layout.